# Xamarin Android Has Double Black Navigation Bar [Android O]

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigationbar

I have an app developed with Xamarin Android. This app works fine in all android's Versions, but in Android Oreo (27) the app has a double black navigation bar like the Image.

[image]

I has proofed changing the styles in all possible forms, but this not works.

Someone know how remove this black space of my Xamarin Android App?. Thanks.

EDIT

My Code for styles is:

```
<resources>

  <style name="MyTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.NoActionBar.Transparent" parent="MyTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyDrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@color/white</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Share your code so we can analize

Comment: that for sure is not a navigation bar. It is just a black part of your layout. There is likely something wrong with your code.

Comment: @G.hakim I edit my question with the styles code

Comment: Use Android monitor or Android Studio to dump your view hierarchy and inspect where this black area origins from. It could also be that your have simply not sized your view to occupy that area.

Comment: I agree with what @Cheesebaron has to say use Android studio with dumped code and check for whats covering the black area

Comment: I guess it is caused by the background of the Divider. But since I cannot see your code, not quite sure. If you post your full code here, It would be more easier to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the error, but I fixed it changing the "Destiny Android Version" in the properties. Android 8.1 (27) instead "Use compile using SDK Version"

[image]

I not change the Android Version for compile.

[image]

And now my app is fine.

[image]